# How to compress textures for use in SceneKit

Tags: textures, scenekit

I tried the **texturetool** in Xcode to compress a bunch of .png textures for use in a SceneKit scene.  Tried several options as per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH108-SW1).

```
  texturetool -e PVRTC --channel-weighting-linear --bits-per-pixel-4 -o ImageL4.pvrtc Image.png
```

The resulting image was 3 to 4 times the size of the original png.  I expected it to be significantly smaller.  These are square textures, power of 2  etc.  Ended up making it smaller and doing a lossy optimization pass.

What is the right approach to texture compression (for iOS10)?

Updated with compression test results.  With this image it was approx. 2x the size. Not surprisingly, the results were the same with textureTool.  The PVRTexTool (from Imagination Technologies) offered a wider variety of formats to choose from.

[image: PVRTests]

Comment: personally, i suggest photoshop and its quite good .png compression for most geometric and vector-ish stuff. And .jpg for images/pictures with visual complexity. And then finding ways to streamline the decompression and use in the app to best benefit of the end user. PVRTC is a bit of a pipedream, I think.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways (off the top of my head) to think about "right" in terms of compression of textures.

1. The storage a texture takes up, and the compromises you're willing to accept in terms of loss of detail in the pursuit of ever smaller texture file sizes. This can include actually physically shrinking a texture, and expanding it later, but is generally fighting with different lossy formats, with consideration of...
2. The extent to which compression impacts the loading time, because all compressed imagery in your package has to be decompressed to be used by the GPU/CPU and your app to present imagery on screen as textures, etc. Some image formats and compression types take MUCH longer to decompress than others. Some are lightning fast, but larger.
3. The final concern is the format you're going to use, in GPU memory, of the texture. This is generally bit details, but there are some more options on some hardware. Is it, 2, 4, 5, 8 bits per colour? How many bits for alpha? etc.

Not all video accelerators and systems cater for multiple formats of texture, but Apple does, as you've probably discovered. Each of these is a blend of tradeoffs in size vs detail. Less bits for colours = less definition of gradients etc. Apple's hardware is also very good at decompressing some formats and terrible at others. And the ultimate size of your package is obviously a different concern on different device types.

You're limited to 200MB on Apple TV, before needing to use some storage management.

100 MB the limit for apps over cell data, etc.

Comment: Am I wrong in expecting a smaller file size after pvrtc compression?  Apple docs and other articles  all imply smaller file size.  Am I missing something in the way using  texturetool ?  Using lossy compression tools like ImageOptim on textures presents other issues - in some cases (but not all), in SceneKit editor, the scene is rendered in just one color, red.

Comment: PVRTC will give you a smaller file size than a NON compressed, bitmap, whether that's .png, TIFF or any other non compressed format. What's not widely known is that most .png exporters (Photoshop etc) actually use (by default) a non-lossy compression. So a simple graphic/vector style image, exported from Photoshop, will be much smaller than the total sum of its bits and bytes of pixels and their colours would be in an uncompressed state. PVRTC is a very mild, very simple compression format that's designed for very rapid decompression on PowerVR GPUs. Hence the name. It's not great compression.

Comment: And .jpg, when used wisely and with complex images (think photos) will give you a much more effective compression than compressed .png or PVRTC could hope to achieve. The cost of .jpg compression is that decompression to the bit exact data required for GPUs and presenting on screen takes much longer than decompression of a PVRTC file. The PVRTC files can be decompressed so rapidly that you can store full sized frames of a video in the format, and decompress them fast enough to show them as video. There's no way .jpg decompression can get anywhere near this speed of decompression, even on a PC.

Comment: Given the quality and effectiveness of .png compression with simple graphical elements, and the compression ratio of .jpg for complex imagery, it's hard to justify using PVRTC for anything other than an image you need rapidly decompressed. This could be your loading screen. For everything else you can probably find ways to stall the player's expectations for long enough to do enough decompression of .jpg and .png assets to get underway.

Comment: @sambro I hope this helps. PVRTC is rapid, low energy decompression, not good ratios of compression. .jpg is high energy decompression, with very good rates of compression, but at some loss of quality. .PNG compression is somewhere in the middle, but suffers size issues with very complex imagery because it tries not to lower quality of imagery, where as .jpg compression will heavily and happily crush some quality and lose details to get smaller file sizes.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly on a tangent to your question but there's a discussion of texture compression including PVRTC [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/how-does-hardware-texture-compression-work/1551#1551).

(**TLDNR**: PNG and JPEG may be good for storage/transmission of texture data but they must be fully decompressed in memory before the GPU accesses them)

However, if you *do* have a texture that compresses well with PNG, there is a good-to-moderate chance that, with a little bit of re-ordering of the data, the compressed PVRTC/ETC/S3TC images may also benefit from lossless compression (e.g. zlib etc), which may then solve your storage problems.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation and links. Updated question with some test data.

Comment: Re the updates: By "No difference in file sizes..in very best quality" I assume you are referring to PVRTexTool + PVRTC. That setting only changes how much *effort* (i.e. CPU cycles) the compression tool puts in when searching for the compressed representation, i.e. trying to reduce the visual differences. The compressed data will always be either 4bpp or 2bpp.
If I get time, I might try to create a 2k*2k image (I assume it's RGB*A*?) that produces ~1MB PNG, and see if I can apply gzip/zlib to it.(I did have a team member working on this but he left before it was completed and was shelved)